# What is the best way to use Panels with the Omega theme?

Tags: views, panels, theming

I am new to drupal 7 so I have some questions about Omega theme.

I've installed Panels/Views and Omega Theme. Using the omega-tools I created a subtheme. How can I use the panels with the omega theme? I see there are two conflicting methodologies here. Is there any tutorial that can help me understand ?

Comment: I don't do theming, so I can't really tell, thus I comment instead of answer. My teams themer shun Omega due to its [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context)-centric nature. As you say, there's a methodology conflict here, and it seems to me you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: I tend to agree with Letharion.  I much prefer Omega + Context, so I shun Panels.  I tried using Omega with Panels and it just doesn't work.  Both workflows have their benefits/drawbacks.  If your preference is Panels, then check out the new [Zen](http://www.drupal.org/project/zen) theme release.  If you simply MUST use Omega, then ditch Panels.  It all comes down to personal preference and needs.

Comment: Seems interesting. I am always baffled by the different flavors of methodologies.

Comment: This could be the subject of a completely different question, but there isn't much to be baffled over. The aged blocks system is not very good. Context takes the blocks system to a whole new level of usefulness, while Panels/Page manager, for better or worse, is far more radical in trying to mostly do away with it all together and replace it with "Panes" instead.

Comment: Hmm I will post a "newbie" question then, about a lot of things and how to do a modern approach in drupal 7 soon. You see, I come from a traditional do-it-yourself-from-scratch philosophy and I am interested in both customizing a system and creating new modules if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Panels, Omega is probably not the way to go.  The lead Omega developer is a big supporter of the Context module (as noted by Letharion) and you can see an example of the slow uptake of panels support [on this thread](http://drupal.org/node/983758).

If you're new to Drupal and want to use Panels, I would recommend trying [Adaptivetheme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme), especially the 3.x branch (currently rc1 but due for a stable release soon).  Adaptivetheme has a long history in the Drupal community and has nearly 30,000 sites using it; it also has the best Panels support of all the major theme frameworks.  The 3.x version of Adaptivetheme adds support for responsive design in Panels, easy CSS resets, etc., making it very comparable to the Omega theme but allowing for excellent Panels support.  There are also a variety of subthemes available (links on the module page) that should give you a good idea of what this theme is capable of.

Comment: What I am trying to do is adapt a layout like this http://www.holiday-rentals.co.uk/ into drupal (I am not going to rent things though). Does adaptivetheme do that?

Comment: If you start from a base theme (which Adaptivetheme is, as is Omega, Fusion, Zen, etc.), you can make any layout you like.  The base themes simply differ in how the theme files are structured; there are different approaches because people work in different ways.

Comment: Although I mentioned I am a Context/Omega guy, for what you want, Panels is _probably_ going to be easier to use, so ditch Omega in this case.

Comment: +1 for adaptivetheme compatability with panels. A good way to see this in action is to download the Drupal Commons distribution http://drupal.org/project/commons

Comment: This is another panels-compitable theme: http://drupal.org/project/kalatheme

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convert a "flexible" panel into an omega compatible region simply by adding the CSS class `grid-4` to the panel container in the panel's CSS settings.  The result is a collapsible omega grid on the front end.  However, the downside is that in the backend, the columns are not visible (you just see stacked regions in the backend).

You could use `grid-1` through `grid-12` in a similar manner to accomplish this.  You might then need to add some CSS to cancel out the default "flexible" panel stuff:

```
.panels-flexible-region-inside,
.panels-flexible-column-inside,
.panels-flexible-row {
  padding: 0;
}
.panels-flexible-column-1-main,
.panels-flexible-region-1-center {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

You'd then need to adjust `margin-left` and `margin-right` accordingly...

It's not a perfect solution, but it worked for me so I figured I'd share this because it's helped me get responsive panels in a very simple omega-based theme.