# Is there any performance issues in using Omega theme with Context, Delta and Panels modules?

Tags: panels, theming, 7

Is there any performance issues in using Omega theme with Context/Delta modules **and** Panels module too? (I mean the context standalone menu, not the one inside panels)

Is there any known issue? I´ve [read about](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31150/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-panels-with-the-omega-theme) some issues with Omega and panels *in the past*, but now they work just fine.
And I need context for my homepage, to create a slighty different layout than the rest of the site.

Comment: Panels can override the home page; this is a built-in feature.  If you only need Context for the home page I would check if there is a way to do it in Panels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, I´m trying that, because having the other two modules just for the homepage kinda sucks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your site and server configuration. if you get alot of anonymous traffic that doesnt require users to login, you should be fine as the cache would handle alot of that load. Also be sure to turn on js / css aggregation. I've built many sites with those modules combined and they run fine. But if your all about performance, you can just do everything by hand and write your own templates/css and not use the bloated ones they have, but you'll be spending alot of time. in that effect you'll have total control over what gets outputted to the user.